# input range not triggering jquery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to change how many decimal place's an output has whenever I change the amount of decimal places I chose

I've tried .change(), .on("mousemove input slidestop"), none of these work

All of the events are being declared within a $(document).ready function

Adding a console.log to the CalculateVolumeConversion shows that it triggers the change event like 40 times whenever I refresh the page, then stops responding afterwards

Image's here because I cant post pictures

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiTOG.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V06Dc.png

Edit: Added code

I've also noticed something, even though the 4 lines are technically the same, only the first one works and calls the method

```
<label for="MFLengthDecimalPlaces">Number of Decimal Places:</label><input type="range" name="MFLengthDecimalPlaces" id="MFLengthDecimalPlaces" min="0" max="10" value="5">

<label for="MFWeightDecimalPlaces">Number of Decimal Places:</label><input type="range" name="MFWeightDecimalPlaces" id="MFWeightDecimalPlaces" min="0" max="10" value="5">

<label for="MFVolumeDecimalPlaces">Number of Decimal Places:</label><input type="range" name="MFVolumeDecimalPlaces" id="MFVolumeDecimalPlaces" min="0" max="10" value="5">

<label for="MFSpeedDecimalPlaces">Number of Decimal Places:</label><input type="range" name="MFSpeedDecimalPlaces" id="MFSpeedDecimalPlaces" min="0" max="10" value="5">
```

---

```
$("#MFLengthConversionInput").on("change", CalculateLengthConversion) <- this one works;

$("#MFWeightDecimalPlaces").on("change", CalculateWeightConversion);

$("#MFVolumeDecimalPlaces").on("change", CalculateVolumeConversion);

$("#MFSpeedDecimalPlaces").on("change", CalculateSpeedConversion);
```

Comment: Please post html and javascript in the question.

Comment: I have screenshots showing my code..., but i guess i'll add it manually

Comment: Checkout this. https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/ukxqL627/5/

Comment: @PlumpAF Just to explain why it's important to not post screenshots of code: When people try to help you, they need to have actual code in order to try to run it and figure out the problem. If you post pictures of the code instead of actual text, people trying to help you now have to re-type all of your code from the pictures, which is incredibly time consuming. You copy/pasting your code into StackOverflow makes it easier for people to help you.